# Stanford Segmenter: How to generate Arabic words segments along with tokens/segments char start offsets and lengths?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Using Stanford Arabic word segmenter, We want to tokenize and segment Arabic text. The ArabicSegmenter does that successfully but the result does not hold the original char offset of the tokens (CoreLabels). Also, the result from ArabicTokenizer, used in ArabicSegmenter class (3.5.2), has all tokens with char offset (i.e. beginning) set to 0.

How to get the Arabic word segments along with the char offset of the resulted CoreLables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character offsets of 0 from `ArabicTokenizer` are due to a bug that is now fixed in the [Github repository](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP). The fix will be included in the next CoreNLP release (3.5.3, scheduled for mid-October 2015). With this fix the `CoreLabel`s returned from `tokenize` should be annotated with correct indices into the original source text, as shown in [this test](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/test/src/edu/stanford/nlp/international/arabic/process/ArabicTokenizerTest.java#L146).

For the time being, `ArabicSegmenter` remains a string-to-string interface, which means there probably isn't a clean way to retrieve the original character offsets from it.